# Julia - Multiplication of values in an array

Tags: arrays, julia, broadcasting, elementwise-operations

If I have an array A with random values, I would like define an array B with, for each i in length A, `B[i] = (A[i])²`

First, I tried the following code:

```
using Distributions

A = rand(Uniform(1,10),1,20)

B = A

for i in 1:20
       B[i] = (A[i])^2
end
```

After these operations, I have A = B

```
A
1×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 26.0478  5.36654  99.675  23.18  …  1.54846  91.3444  9.41496  2.91666

B
1×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 26.0478  5.36654  99.675  23.18  …  1.54846  91.3444  9.41496  2.91666
```

So I tried an other method:

```
B = A^2
```

There is the following error:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("A has dimensions (1,20) but B has dimensions (1,20)")
```

If I do, for instance, `B = 2*A` it works fine...

Some ideas to help ?

Thank you

Comment: You have a major misconception here: `B = A` does not make a copy — both `B` and `A` will be two names for the same data.  You want `B = copy(A)` to make a copy.

Comment: The reason `A^2` doesn't work, is that it is the same as `A*A`, and you cannot multiply two vectors together. Instead you must specify that you want element-by-element operation, which is what `.*` will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest solution here is to use broadcasting via `.`.

```
julia> A = rand(Uniform(1,10),1,20)
1×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 8.84251  1.90331  8.5116  2.50216  …  1.67195  9.68628  4.05879  1.50231

julia> B = A .^ 2
1×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 78.19  3.62257  72.4473  6.26081  …  2.7954  93.8241  16.4738  2.25693
```

This gives you what you expect:

```
julia> A
1×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 8.84251  1.90331  8.5116  2.50216  …  1.67195  9.68628  4.05879  1.50231

julia> B
1×20 Array{Float64,2}:
 78.19  3.62257  72.4473  6.26081  …  2.7954  93.8241  16.4738  2.25693
```

This `.` operator works with any function and what it does it broadcasts (applies) all the function to each and every element of the array/object.

Here's an example with a custom function:

```
julia> my_func(a) = a * 5
my_func (generic function with 1 method)

julia> my_func.(1:5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
  5
 10
 15
 20
 25
```

Have a look at [the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you @niczky12

Comment: Why do you do `B = copy(A)` and then `B = B.^2`? This is an unnecessary step and does extra allocations. Why not directly call `B = A.^2`?

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to follow the original question as closely as possible. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Also, if you change it to `A.=A.^2`, it will remove one more copy.